# Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a script manager in master page. Now I want to add a TextBox Calendar Extender to my child page. When I add a ToolscriptManager into child page it shows me an error:

> "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page."

Am I able to add the calendar extender to this page? I am using AjaxControlToolkit3.5. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: As it suggests, you can only add one ScriptManager per page.  Why do you need the child instance?

Answer (score 2):

There can only ever be one real ScriptManager. If you have a ScriptManager on your Master page, then in your pages you would use a [`ScriptManagerProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx). This will act as a proxy to the real ScriptManager on your master page. It provides the same functionality as the ScriptManager for the most part, and you would use it the same way.

Comment: Shows "The control with ID 'ScriptManagerProxy1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it."